# Laravel + VueJS Application Laravel Passport {"message":"Unauthenticated."} Problem

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-passport

I started to develop the Laravel + VueJS dashboard application. But I have a problem with security.
When I enter this URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user without log in I seeing request answer.
I started researching the Internet to find a solution to the problem. As a result of my research, I found the Laravel Passport. I set it up as described on the [official page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport), but I didn't succeed. But the application is constantly responding. **{"message":"Unauthenticated."}**

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    /**  
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return User::latest()->paginate(100);

    }



    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //return['message'=>'I have data'];
        //return $request->all();

        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
        ]);

        return User::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'type' => $request['type'],
            'bio' => $request['bio'],
            'photo' => $request['photo'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
    }


    public function profile()
    {
        return auth('api')->user();    

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
            'password' => 'sometimes|min:6'
        ]);

        $user->update($request->all());

        return ['message' => 'update'];
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->delete();
        return['message' => 'User Deleted'];
    }
}
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;


class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
         'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::routes();
        Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(1));

        //
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'bio', 'photo', 'type'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**Request Syntax**

```
axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) => (this.users = data.data));
```

From my research, I think everything seems right. But I'm making my improvements with Wamp server on Windows. Do you think that's going to be a problem? Do I need to make settings on the htaccess file like this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Did you have set Bearer token in the header of that request ??

Comment: I guess I didn't. Can you tell me how to do this? Or can you suggest a tutorial? @HOSSAINAZADSHOHAG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following lines to Kernel.php and my problem was resolved.

**Kernel.php**

```
  'web' => [
            \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the Authorization header with Bearer [your token] to the request and send it again, then check if it still returns Unauthenticated.